# Find functions that satisfy this equation.

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Give some examples of functions, $F$ and $G$ such that $$x=\sqrt{F(x)+G(x)\sqrt{F(x+n)}}-\sqrt{F(x+n)}.$$ $n$ can be a constant.

[Edit]: with $n\gt{0}$

Comment: For $x\ge 0$, $F(x)=x^2, \,\,G(x)=3|x|,\,\, n=0$

Comment: Thanks but I just edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Just choose some expression for $F$ and solve for $G$. $F(x)=x^2$ makes the things easy, for example:
$$x=\sqrt{x^2+G(x)(x+n)}-(x+n)$$
$$(2x+n)^2=x^2+G(x)(x+n)$$
$$G(x)=\frac{3x^2+4xn+n^2}{x+n}=3x+n$$

Comment: But this still should be for $x>-n$, otherwise you should put absolute values of $(x+n)$